# syllogism question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

[image]

I drew two euler's diagrams

[image]

and concluded that option $b.)$ is correct,

but in the book option $c.)$ is given correct.

Answer (score 1):

Answer (b) is correct in the sense that conclusion II certainly follows from A and B.   It is the strongest conclusion.

However, if conclusion II, then either conclusion I or conclusion II (via Disjunctive introduction).   So answer (c) is also *not wrong*; although it is weaker than answer (b).

Note that answer (c) is "I *or* II follows", which is distinct from answer (e) "I *and* II follows"

---

PS: However, I too would have picked the strongest answer.

Comment: So is the option $b.)$ correct ?